# Blank Page after include command

Tags: php, debian

If I use a code like this:

```
<?php

echo 'Text';

include("Class/MyClass.php");

echo 'Text';

?>
```

This code only returns one 'Text'. (The one before the include)
I don't get an error (error reporting on), and the code works on my local XAMPP.

Debian 6.0 / PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologize in advance - it's not the answer but just wild guesses.

1. "Class/MyClass.php" (or any file it includes) contains somewhere `exit()` or `die()` calls that depend on configuration.
2. Try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and  `ini_set('display_errors', '1')` right before including.

Comment: Thank you.

I had something like this in the beginning of my included file:

    if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"])
        exit;

Thanks :))